# Is it possible to avoid Time-dependent workflow email firing on a past 'scheduled' date?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time-dependant workflow to fire 15, 7 and 1 day before a set date. 
Let's taken an example.

- Today is 1/22/2015
- Due date set is 1/23/2015
- 1 day email is scheduled for 1/22/2015 (today)
- 7 days email is scheduled for 1/16/2015 (past date)
- 15 days email is scheduled for 1/8/2015 (past date)

But I get all 3 emails today (1/22/2015), My expectation in this scenario is to get only 1 email for 1 day. How to avoid past date emails within the same workflow rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good discussion of time based workflow actions for dates in the past here: [Should time-based workflows trigger upon record update that puts trigger date in the past?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58209/should-time-based-workflows-trigger-upon-record-update-that-puts-trigger-date-in?rq=1)

It quotes the documentation https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

> If a workflow rule has a time trigger set for a time in the past,
>   Salesforce queues the associated time-dependent actions to start
>   executing within one hour.

So I think you will have to have 3 separate workflows, so that

- if the Due Date is less than 15 days from now, but more than 7 days from now, the 15-day email is not included in the actions
- if the Due Date is less than 7 days from now, but more than 1 day from now, the 15-day email and the 7-day email are not included in the actions